# Como guardar la reproducción de un video en base de datos, desde php

Tags: mysqli, php7, codeigniter-4

Que tal amigos como estan, gracias de ante mano.

Tengo un video en un CRM al cual se le dara permiso algunos usuarios a verlos. Para tener el contro de quien lo ha visto y hasta donde ha visto el video debo guardar el avance de reproduccion del video en base de datos.

Es lo que me dice la lógica pero no se como hacerlo, me pueden ayudar? gracias

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Tienes las etiquetas php y codeigniter, pero no hay código relacionado en tu pregunta. Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Answer (score 0):

Para poder registrar el avance de la reproducción del video, una posible solución es que te crees una API con un endpoint de usuario y video donde le pases el milisegundo de reproducción del video para poder registrarlo en la base de datos. A partir de aquí, con un javascript puedes programar un intervalo para que cada 100ms envie el currentTime del video a la API y así quedar registrado.

Ejemplo:

```
<video id="video" width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<script>
  setInterval(() => {
    var vid = document.getElementById("video");
    vid.currentTime; // Variable para enviar a la API
  }, 100);
```